# check if class exists with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through Html and find if an element has a specific child:

```
$('#thisFormat article div p').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).parent().find('.specialclass').length) {
    var LowerTrue="Yes";
    IsLower.push(LowerTrue);} 
    else{
    var LowerTrue="No";
    IsLower.push(LowerTrue);
    };                              

});
```

But I only get `No` answers though some elements has that `specialclass`. Also there is a `::before` tag in the element that I want to check if it exists:

```
<i title="Exists" class="specialclass">
  ::before
</i>
```

So is it possible to solve my problem? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="thisFormat">
    <article>
        <div>
            <p  class="specialclass">
                <i title="Hello" class="specialclass">
                    ::before
                </i>
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>
        <article>
           <div>
            <p  class="specialclass">
            </p>
           </div>
       </article>
</div>
```

This works:

```
$('#thisFormat article div p').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).children("i").length) {
    var LowerTrue="Yes";
    IsLower.push(LowerTrue);} 
    else{
    var LowerTrue="No";
    IsLower.push(LowerTrue);
    };                              

});
```

Comment: are the elements with your class nested inside the targeted p?

Comment: Are you sure `.length` isn't 2?

Comment: @SLaks get the same answer if I only put `.length` in the end:)

Comment: Add working code snippet please.

Comment: Post the related HTML.

Comment: If the elements you're looking for are children of `p`, why then would you use `$(this).parent().find(....)`? .. why not just `$(this).find(.....)`?

Comment: @PeterKA that does not work. I will post HTML soon.

Comment: working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s4t9eqw5/ if your i is inside the p tag, remove .parent()

Comment: @loli I updated the fiddle. I get `::before`

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/kp617mcr/ The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Juhana please see my edit with HTML, here.

Comment: If you click on the link on my previous comment you'll see that it uses your HTML and it works fine.

Comment: @Juhana the fiddle outputs `Yes,Yes` while it should be `Yes,No`...

Comment: ??? the second paragraph has the class you want.

Comment: @Juhana See the edit in your fiddle. What I want to do is check each `article` element and find out if the `p` tag inside each article has an `i` element or not!

Comment: Then why do you use `.parent()` if you want the **children** of `<p>`? You'll have to provide a link to the modified jsfiddle, I can't see it otherwise.

Comment: @Juhana http://jsfiddle.net/kp617mcr/2/ please check it out:)

Comment: Again, **???** It outputs "Yes,No" (if you just output the array.) http://jsfiddle.net/kp617mcr/3/

Comment: @Juhana Sorry, I am a beginner... I found a solution that works. See my edit.. And thanks for your feedback!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for the `::before` tag inside your `.each()` you can do

```
$(/* get the <i> you want */).html == '::before';
```

The problem with your array is that by asking the `parent()` you are targetting the div, while you say the `<i>`'s are in `<p>`'s

Try the following

```js
var IsLower = []

$('#thisFormat article div p').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('.specialclass').length == 1) {
    var LowerTrue = "Yes";
    IsLower.push(LowerTrue);
  } else {
    var LowerTrue = "No";
    IsLower.push(LowerTrue);
  };
});

$('#out').html(IsLower);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="thisFormat">
  <article>
    <div>

      <p>
        <i title="Exists">
</i>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i title="Exists" class="specialclass">
</i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: I found a solution, see my edit. But I will accept your answer, I think I did present an incorrect HTML. ANd your solution works for that html!

Comment: Glad you found a solution, sorry I couldn't adress your actual problem